# Intersection of two linked lists without duplicities

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, linked-list

Given two sorted linked lists, where the result should be intersection without duplicities.

- Creating of new nodes is not allowed.
- The resulting list will be composed of the elements of the original lists.

*Inputs are two lists separated by empty line*:

*L1* -> 2 3 3 4 4 4 5

*L2* -> 3 4 5 6 7

*Result* -> 3 4 5

I have my solution below, but creating new node in **IntersectionDestruct** function.

Is there any simple way how to change *IntersectionDestruct* function with the logic of not creating any new node?

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

def PrintLinkedList( p ):
    print( "Result:", end=" " )
    while p!=None:
        print( p.data, end=" " )
        p = p.next
    print(".")

def ReadLinkedList():
    first = None
    last = None
    r = input()
    while r!="":
        row = r.split()
        if len(row)==0:
            break
        for s in row:
            p = Node(int(s),None)
            if first==None:
                first = p
            else:
                last.next = p
            last = p
        r = input()
return first

def LLIntersection(a, b):
    head = tail = None

    while a and b:
        if a.data == b.data:
            if head is None:
                head = Node(a.data, head)
                tail = head
            else:
                tail.next = Node(a.data, tail.next)
                tail = tail.next

            a = a.next
            b = b.next

        # advance the smaller list
        elif a.data < b.data:
            a = a.next
        else:
            b = b.next
    return head
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code, e.g., on line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't actually prevent duplicates, if you have a repeated number in both lists then advancing a and b together results in them matching again and the duplicate coming through in the result.

You should instead advance them both to a *new* number which would prevent any duplicates.

Then just reuse the original Nodes as well by assigning a to the list and clearing its next value so it doesn't leak into the existing list.

```py
def IntersectionUnique(a, b):
    head = tail = None

    while a and b:
        if a.data == b.data:
            if head is None:
                head = tail = a
            else:
                tail.next = a
                tail = a
            
            # Skip past all duplicates (careful for end of list!)
            while a.next and a.data == a.next.data:
                a = a.next
            while b.next and b.data == b.next.data:
                b = b.next

            # Advance to new values
            a = a.next
            b = b.next
            
            # Clear tail
            tail.next = None

        # advance the smaller list
        elif a.data < b.data:
            a = a.next
        else:
            b = b.next
    return head
```

As this overwrites the next values on nodes from a, walking the list from a after this will give the same as before using the function up until the first item that intersected which had its next overwritten, then will be the intersecting values only after that.

So consider it corrupted, use the return value only.

Comment: Good job. Nits: `Skip past all duplicates` is not what what the `while`-loops do: they advance to the last repetition. You don't need to set `tail.next` more than once: do it just before the `return`. You don't need to skip repetitions in both lists: replace the tail of the outer loop with `while a and a.data == b.data:
                a = a.next` or no worse.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, they advance to the last repetition to guarantee that the advance to new values is always a new value - thus, skipping all duplicated values.
It does not set `tail.next` twice, tail has a _different value_ at those two points, the first time sets the existing tail to point to the new Node, then updates tail to point to the new Node too, the second time is setting next on the new Node.
You could just advance a and repeat the outer loop+comparisons multiple times to advance b, but that gives a less clear execution flow and I was updating _their_  code to make it clear for them.

Comment: Thanks so much Ashley, this solution fits much better expected results.